# Segregate list of patterns based on given prefix

Tags: javascript, regex, string, permutation

I have an ordered list of strings like this where the right side digit of the '-' can increment to any number.

```
let arr = ['1-0/2-0/3-0', '1-0/2-0/3-1', '1-0/2-1/3-0', '1-1/2-0/3-0', '1-1/2-1/3-0', '1-1/2-1/3-1', '1-1/2-2/3-0']
```

I want to extract them into an array/list based on some **prefix** and group them by the immediate digit after prefix.

Eg 1: If the given prefix is `1-`, then the output array should contain two entries

```
[['1-0/2-0/3-0', '1-0/2-0/3-1', '1-0/2-1/3-0'], ['1-1/2-0/3-0', '1-1/2-1/3-0', '1-1/2-1/3-1', '1-1/2-2/3-0']]
```

Eg 2: If the given prefix is `1-1/2-`, then the output array should contain **three entries**

```
[['1-1/2-0/3-0'], ['1-1/2-1/3-0', '1-1/2-1/3-1'], ['1-1/2-2/3-0']]
```

I'm looking for the better trick(like using regular expressions) other than brute-force approach.

Comment: How is your input formatted? Can you change it to the way it's defined in code, such as `arr = ['1-0/2-0/3-0', '1-0/2-0/3-1', ...`, or whatever it is, and show your expected output (in code format)? Can you also post what you've tried so far?

Comment: At least show us your brute force approach. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for others to help you improve your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you simply have an array of items. Then performing the prefix match is easily done with `startsWith`:

```
const filtered = arr.filter(a => a.startsWith(prefix))
```

Then it looks like you are grouping up to the first `/` after the prefix. You could use `reduce` to do this, but `groupBy` in lodash makes it very easy. Working example:

```js
const arr = [
  '1-0/2-0/3-0',
  '1-0/2-0/3-1',
  '1-0/2-1/3-0',
  '1-1/2-0/3-0',
  '1-1/2-1/3-0',
  '1-1/2-1/3-1',
  '1-1/2-2/3-0'
]

const prefix = '1-1/2-'

const filtered = arr.filter(a => a.startsWith(prefix))
const groups = _.groupBy(filtered, i => i.slice(prefix.length).split('/')[0])
const values = _.values(groups)
console.log(values)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Exactly what I want. Great @matt-way

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple functional way to do this with plain javascript. I'm assuming looping through the list doesn't count as brute force. I'm also assuming that you want to group by the first character after the prefix, but that wan't explicit in your question. Basically filter out the non-prefixed items and the build an object keyed to the first character after the prefix:

```js
let list = ["1-0/2-0/3-0","1-0/2-0/3-1","1-0/2-1/3-0","1-1/2-0/3-0","1-1/2-1/3-0","1-1/2-1/3-1","1-1/2-2/3-0"]

function segregate(prefix, list){
   return Object.values(
     list.filter(str => str.startsWith(prefix))
     .reduce((obj, str) => {
       let key = str[prefix.length]
       if (!obj[key]) obj[key] = []
       obj[key].push(str)
       return obj
     }, {})
   )

}

console.log("with '1-'")
console.log(segregate("1-", list))

console.log("with '1-1/2-'")
console.log(segregate("1-1/2-", list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to create a tree from the prefixes that looks like the following:

```
{
    '1': {
    letters: ['1-0/2-0/3-0',
              '1-0/2-0/3-1',
              '1-0/2-1/3-0', ...]
    children: {
        '0/2': {
        letters: [...],
        children: {
          ...
        }
      }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Then given a prefix, we can traverse this tree to find the appropriate letter groups. This approach has a better runtime as you don't need to traverse the entire list of prefixes (assuming that is much larger than the "depth" of the prefixes):

```js
const strings = [
  '1-0/2-0/3-0',
  '1-0/2-0/3-1',
  '1-0/2-1/3-0',
  '1-1/2-0/3-0',
  '1-1/2-1/3-0',
  '1-1/2-1/3-1',
  '1-1/2-2/3-0'
]

function insert(path, letter, tree) {
  if (path.length > 0) {
    let [node, ...remaining] = path;
    if (node in tree) tree[node].letters.push(letter);
    else tree[node] = {children: {}, letters: [letter]};
    insert(remaining, letter, tree[node].children);
  }
}

const prefixTree = strings.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  insert(curr.split('-'), curr, acc);
  return acc;
}, {});


function getLetters(prefix) {
  function get(path, tree) {
    if (path.length === 1)
      return Object.values(tree[path[0]].children)
                   .map(v => v.letters);
    return get(path.slice(1), tree[path[0]].children);
  }
  return get(prefix.split('-').filter(s => s !== ''), prefixTree);
}

console.log(getLetters('1-'));
console.log(getLetters('1-1/2-'));

console.log('Prefix tree looks like the following');
console.log(prefixTree);
```